# La respuesta de un servicio web es una stdClass Object extraña

Tags: php, webservice

Me pidieron hacer una tabla de personas con los datos que me brinda un servicio web hecho en *.net*.

Usé PHP para poder listar todo el contenido del servicio web y el resultado es el siguiente objeto:

```
stdClass Object([ListarStaffMedicoResult] => {
"List": [{
    "COD_MEDICO": "16610",
    "DSC_NMEDICO": "FUNG QUINTANILLA ROSA ELIZABETH",
    "COD_ESPECIALID": "018",
    "DSC_ESPECIALIDAD": "PSICOLOGIA",
    "FOTO": "[00149][00150][00151][00152][00153][00157][00158][00159][00183][00369][00370][00410][00425][00509]16610.jpg"
}, {
    "COD_MEDICO": "19904",
    "DSC_NMEDICO": "ESPINO HUAMAN JAVIER ENRIQUE",
    "COD_ESPECIALID": "050",
    "DSC_ESPECIALIDAD": "PEDIATRIA Y NEONATOLOGIA",
    "FOTO": "[00149][00150][00151][00152][00153][00157][00158][00159][00183][00369][00370][00410][00425][00509]19904.jpg"
}, {
    "COD_MEDICO": "40767",
    "DSC_NMEDICO": "ALANIA CHAVEZ PAUL FRANCIS",
    "COD_ESPECIALID": "228",
    "DSC_ESPECIALIDAD": "TRAUMATOLOGIA - UNIDAD DE MANO Y PIE",
    "FOTO": "[00149][00150][00151][00152][00153][00157][00158][00159][00183][00369][00370][00410][00425][00509]40767.jpg"
}, {
    "COD_MEDICO": "51412",
    "DSC_NMEDICO": "CASTRO MUJICA MARIA DEL CARMEN ",
    "COD_ESPECIALID": "226",
    "DSC_ESPECIALIDAD": "NO_USAR GENETICA",
    "FOTO": "[00149][00150][00151][00152][00153][00157][00158][00159][00183][00369][00370][00410][00425][00509]51412.jpg"
}],
"TotalRecords": 272})
```

Debo mencionar que he eliminado los elementos que estaban de más (para no recargar la página).

¿Cuál es el problema entonces? es que nunca he visto un objeto así. No tengo ni idea de cómo listar los elementos ya que al momento de usar un `foreach` me sale un error de que el `foreach` está mal hecho, y si quiero obtener algún valor de algún índice me doy con la sorpresa de que el único indice es `ListarStaffMedicoResult` y su contenido es todo lo demás sin poder acceder al mismo.

¿Saben cómo acceder a los datos para listarlos de, por ejemplo, esta forma?:

```
Nombre doctor: FUNG QUINTANILLA ROSA ELIZABETH
Especialidad: PSICOLOGIA

Nombre doctor: ESPINO HUAMAN JAVIER ENRIQUE
Especialidad: PEDIATRIA Y NEONATOLOGIA

Etc.
```

Comment: PD: Te recomiendo usar [`var_export()`](https://php.net/es/var_export) en vez de [`var_dump()`](https://php.net/es/var_dump) para ver el contenido de una variable. El resultado será fácilmente reproducible copiando/pegando el texto.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir lo que te devuelve el servicio web haciendo uso de [`var_export()`](https://php.net/es/var_export) como te recomiendo en el comentario anterior? Así podríamos reproducir con exactitud lo que te devuelve el servicio web o lo que uses para acceder a él.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas! No te preocupes por el `stdClass`, no es mas que una representación genérica y vacía que ofrece PHP para representar un objeto cualquiera que sea, el problema aquí es sencillo y es que el `array` que contiene presenta varios niveles de `anidacion`, por eso un `foreach` de golpe no te va a devolver el resultado que necesitas.

Puedes convertirla fácilmente en un `array`:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Después `ListarStaffMedicoResult` seria la única clave que encontramos en el primer nivel, dentro de este encontramos otras dos claves `List` y `TotalRecords`.

La clave que tu quieres iterar realmente es `List`, que es la que contiene una colección de objetos con la información.

Puedes hacer por tanto:

```
foreach($array["ListarStaffMedicoResult"]["List"] as $result) {...}
```

y ahí ya accedes a cada propiedad que te interese, como

```
$result["DSC_NMEDICO"].
```

Comment: Por desgracia [`get_object_vars()`](https://php.net/get_object_vars) sólo obtendría las propiedades de la clase `ListarStaffMedicoResult`, y no las de cada elemento de la propiedad `List`, por lo que habría que usar `$result->DSC_NMEDICO` en vez de `$result["DSC_NMEDICO"]`. Además, te recomiendo trabajar siempre con el tipo de datos original y no ir convirtiendo de clase a matriz sólo por usar la forma de acceder a índices de matrices para acceder a sus propiedades.

Answer (score 0):

El formato en el que compartes el contenido del resultado parece haber sido generado con `var_dump()`, pero te recomiendo encarecidamente uses `var_export()` para este trabajo ya que de esa manera podremos reproducir con exactitud su contenido.

Aún así vamos a intentar analizar la exportación paso a paso para entender qué datos estamos recibiendo:

```
stdClass Object([ListarStaffMedicoResult] => {
```

Esto nos indica que la variable exportada es directamente una instancia de la clase `stdClass` con una propiedad llamada `ListarStaffMedicoResult` que contiene una clase sin nombre con las propiedades que detallo a continuación.

Lo que muestro a continuación indica que la propiedad `ListarStaffMedicoResult` tiene, a su vez, una propiedad llamada `List` cuyo contenido es una matriz que puede tener cero o varios elementos:

```
"List": [
    ...
]
```

Cada elemento es una clase sin nombre (delimitada por `{ ... }`) con las siguientes propiedades:

```
"COD_MEDICO": "...",
"DSC_NMEDICO": "...",
"COD_ESPECIALID": "...",
"DSC_ESPECIALIDAD": "...",
"FOTO": "..."
```

Y, por último, hay una propiedad llamada `TotalRecords`:

```
"TotalRecords": 272
```

Una vez que conocemos el contenido de la variable (llamémosla `$variable`), podemos iterar los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
/* Iteramos por cada elemento de la matriz contenida en la propiedad "List" de "ListarStaffMedicoResult" */
foreach ($variable->ListarStaffMedicoResult->List as $elemento) {
  /* Mostramos el contenido de las propiedades del elemento deseado */
  echo '<li>Nombre doctor: ', $elemento->DSC_NMEDICO, '</li>', PHP_EOL,
    '<li>Especialidad: ', $elemento->DSC_ESPECIALIDAD, '</li>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

**Ejemplo:**

Se puede ver el funcionamiento en línea [pulsando aquí](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/byFs):

```
<?php
$variable = (object) [
    'ListarStaffMedicoResult' => (object) [
        'List' => [
            (object) [
                'COD_MEDICO' => '16610',
                'DSC_NMEDICO' => 'FUNG QUINTANILLA ROSA ELIZABETH',
                'COD_ESPECIALID' => '018',
                'DSC_ESPECIALIDAD' => 'PSICOLOGIA',
                'FOTO' => '',
            ],
            (object) [
                'COD_MEDICO' => '19904',
                'DSC_NMEDICO' => 'ESPINO HUAMAN JAVIER ENRIQUE',
                'COD_ESPECIALID' => '050',
                'DSC_ESPECIALIDAD' => 'PEDIATRIA Y NEONATOLOGIA',
                'FOTO' => '',
            ],
        ],
        'TotalRecords' => 0,
    ]
];
/* Iteramos por cada elemento de la matriz contenida en la propiedad "List" */
foreach ($variable->ListarStaffMedicoResult->List as $elemento) {
  /* Mostramos el contenido de las propiedades del elemento deseado */
  echo '<li>Nombre doctor: ', $elemento->DSC_NMEDICO, '</li>', PHP_EOL,
    '<li>Especialidad: ', $elemento->DSC_ESPECIALIDAD, '</li>', PHP_EOL;
}
?><pre><?php var_export($variable); ?></pre>
```